# How to change the view of the previous fragment after returning to it using the back button?

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, onbackpressed

I have an activity with two fragments.

The second one is called when I click on something to the first.

What I want is this : if i click on "back" button, I want to go back to the first fragment (that is working), but I want to set the visibility to **VISIBLE** on an element (if the first fragment is called with back press only)

How do I do that ?

I tried something like this (in my main fragment), I've found the idea in another topic, but this is trigger always in my main activity :

```
    override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    view?.isFocusableInTouchMode = true
    view?.requestFocus()
    view?.setOnKeyListener { v, keyCode, event ->
        if(event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
            Log.i(TAG, "backpress pressed")
            return@setOnKeyListener true
        }
        return@setOnKeyListener false
    }
}
```

Temporary solution :

I've created a companion object with a value true or false and I change it everytime I need it, but it's temporary only.

Comment: Have any code example to show us?

Comment: See y updated answer

Comment: do you have a listener concept?

Comment: @ProjetSin Please stop using keywords in your questions titles, you have the tags at the bottom to indicate the scope of your questions. *...but it's temporary only.* - Isn't this what you want?

Comment: What do you mean by "listener concept" ? @Luksprog ok i'll stop, sorry. And yes, t's what I want and it's working, but I want to know if there's a more proper solution for that (so that's why it's temporary)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your second `Fragment` replaces the first (i.e. using `FragmentTransaction#replace`), your first Fragment (we'll call them `FragmentA` and `FragmentB`) will be paused (i.e. `onPause()` will be called on `FragmentA`).

When you press the back button, the backstack will be popped, and `FragmentA` will be resumed (i.e. `onResume()` will be called).

What I would recommend, is to save a boolean flag in `FragmentA`, and set it to `true` when you show `FragmentB`. Then, in `FragmentA#onResume`, you can check if the flag is set to `true`, and set it back to `false` while handing the case that you wanted.

For example, something like:

```
private const val STATE_WAITING_FOR_FRAGMENT_B = "state_waiting_b"

class FragmentA : Fragment() {
    private var isWaitingForFragmentB: Boolean = false

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            isWaitingForFragmentB = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(STATE_WAITING_FOR_FRAGMENT_B)
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        if (isWaitingForFragmentB) {
            isWaitingForFragmentB = false
            // handle your view state here
        }
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
        savedInstanceState.putBoolean(
            STATE_WAITING_FOR_FRAGMENT_B,
            isWaitingForFragmentB
        )
    }

    private fun showFragmentB() {
        isWaitingForFragmentB = true
        // do fragment transaction here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not good at grammar.

First fragment do not call *resume function* when returning.

You must create callback with *interface*.

Answer (score 0):

A good approach should be passing some flag, on the second fragment, by activity intent and to capture it on the first Fragment on `onResume()`

If you need extra info, just let me know

Comment: Yes please give me more details

Comment: what exactly do you didnt understand?

Comment: The flag, what is it ?

Comment: just pass value by 'intent.putExtra' and capture on the other fragment